# Getting an error when attempting to send transactions to the TPU from a Rust client

Tags: send-transaction, solana-client

When attempting to send transactions to the TPU from a Rust client using a TpuClient connection, I am encountering the following error:

`panicked at 'QuicLazyInitializedEndpoint::create_endpoint bind_in_range: Custom { kind: Other, error: "No available UDP ports in (8000, 10000)" }`

Any insight as to what is happening here? From what I can gather, RPCs compete for a limited number of QUIC connections on the validators. Would this potentially suggest that there was high demand during this specific slot and so a connection was not able to be made? Any other ideas? And any ideas on how to get around this?

Answer (score 2):

Your client is trying to send to the old TPU port, which used to accept UDP. Now you must configure your client to use QUIC.

That code has changed a lot recently, so the easiest thing might be to update your crates to version 1.14, which defaults to using QUIC everywhere.

Comment: I am still getting the same error despite using crate version 1.14. It is pointing to this line of code: https://docs.rs/solana-client/latest/src/solana_client/nonblocking/quic_client.rs.html#98

The error is occuring when this function is called: solana_net_utils::bind_in_range, which is defined here: https://docs.rs/solana-net-utils/latest/src/solana_net_utils/lib.rs.html#431-447.

It looks like that always returns a UdpSocket. I guess QUIC is still using UDP sockets then right? Any other thoughts on what might be occurring here?

Comment: Yeah correct, it's using a UDP socket under the hood, so this points to an issue in your testing machine, since it's failing to bind to a port. Do you have networking privileges on that machine?

Comment: Yeah this error doesn't occur immediately, it usually occurs after a while. My guess was that as I am connecting from an RPC that isn't a staked validator, I am getting booted out of the 500 available QUIC ports due to high demand for connections.

Comment: You may be creating too many TPU clients in that case. Have you tried creating one and then reusing that for the whole of your run?

Comment: Yeah I just create one TPU client and use it across various threads as needed.

Comment: Ah darn. Since you're connecting from an RPC node actually, it's probably happening that you're sometimes getting a collision when requesting a socket, and trying to use a port already used by the RPC node.

Comment: Oh right, is there a better way to make a connection / send packets that you can think of?

Comment: You're doing things right on your side, but it's up to the TPU client to be better about choosing ports.  You could hack this line https://docs.rs/solana-client/latest/src/solana_client/nonblocking/quic_client.rs.html#96 to be something bigger than `VALIDATOR_PORT_RANGE`, ie pass in `(8_000, 60_000)` instead, and use that instead

Comment: Ok I'll give that a go, cheers