# How to fix solana rpc node from crashing due to no available udp ports for QUIC?

Tags: solana-program, solana-cli, validator

I am running an RPC node and using the quic client to send transactions on the same machine. The node will run for a few hours, with many successful transactions sent via quic and then crash with the following error.

```
thread 'sol-warm-quic-service' panicked at 'QuicLazyInitializedEndpoint::create_endpoint bind_in_range: Custom { kind: Other, error: "No available UDP ports in (8000, 10000)" }', client/>
```

In the comments in [this post](https://solana.stackexchange.com/questions/5127/getting-an-error-when-attempting-to-send-transactions-to-the-tpu-from-a-rust-cli) the solution provided is to modify the VALIDATOR_PORT_RANGE to (8000, 60000) in the [quic no blocking file](https://docs.rs/solana-client/latest/src/solana_client/nonblocking/quic_client.rs.html#96). I have done this and am still encountering the same issue. How can I better specify who is using which ports?

Comment: Very strange... Maybe you can see how all of those ports are being used with something like `ss -tulpn`?

Comment: Hi Jon. I ran ss - tulpn, I am getting validator process, and transaction sender process in port range between 8000, 10000. I am also seeing validator process and transaction sender process in ports > 10000. I assume this is unexpected as only  the transaction sender process should be > 10000? 
Further context - I didn't modify any validator code, only the solana_client crate which is imported into the transaction sender bot.

Comment: This may be a silly suggestion, but how about keeping the validator to (8000, 10000), and changing your client to (10001, 60000)?

Comment: Ok I think this might be working. Thanks for your help